# Confusion related to a derivation

Tags: gaussian-process

I was reading this paper http://cs.ru.nl/~perry/publications/2011/ICANN2011/groot-icann2011.pdf and I am a bit confused how this was derived

$p(f|Y)  \propto p(f)*p(Y|f)  \propto exp^{(-\frac{1}{2}f^TK^{-1}f-\frac{1}{2}(Y-f)^T\Sigma^{-1}(Y-f))}$

is Gaussian processN(m,V) $ \propto exp^{-\frac{1}{2}f^TV^{-1}f + fV^{-1}m}$

with mean and covariance given by

$m=(K^{-1}+\Sigma^{-1})^{-1}\Sigma^{-1}Y$

$V=(K^{-1}+\Sigma^{-1})^{-1}$

Is this the right way to derive it

$p(f|Y)  \propto p(f)*p(Y|f)  \propto exp^{(-\frac{1}{2}f^TK^{-1}f-\frac{1}{2}(Y-f)^T\Sigma^{-1}(Y-f))}$ $\propto exp^{(-\frac{1}{2}f^TK^{-1}f-\frac{1}{2}(f-Y)^T\Sigma^{-1}(f-Y))}$ product of two gaussian so the mean and covariance of the product of two gaussians

[image]

and I eventually get
$m=(K^{-1}+\Sigma^{-1})^{-1}\Sigma^{-1}Y$

$V=(K^{-1}+\Sigma^{-1})^{-1}$

However, I still don't get how it was manipulated(the expression) to get

$ \propto exp^{-\frac{1}{2}f^TV^{-1}f + fV^{-1}m}$

Comment: It is clear that you can write the equation in the form of normal distribution (exponent of quadratic form), so it is a normal distribution (normalization constant handles everything because it is a probability distribution). To get mean and variance just group all terms to differ quadratic and linear terms.

Comment: @Alexey can u elaborate a bit more

Comment: What @Alexey means is that when the argument of the exponential is written as a homogeneous quadratic form in $f-m$ with matrix $A$, where $m$ and $A$ do not depend on $f$, then $m$ is the mean and the inverse of $A$ is the variance. These are the most basic properties of the [multivariate Gaussian distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution) (and often are taken as a definition). Thus, his comment shows that your question is really one of elementary algebra.

Comment: @whuber. Yeah but I just need to know how the expression was manipulated to get $exp ^{-\frac{1}{2}f^TV^{-1}f+fV^{-1}m}$

Comment: @whuber. I made some changes in the question to get the answer. Is my answer correct?